# NHibernate linq extensions order child objects collection

Tags: c#, database, linq, nhibernate

I'm trying to query my db with NH Linq extensions and here is where I am stuck:

I have a `Customer` object and it has a property of type `Order`, and `Order` has an `ICollection<Orderline>` collection, and lastly `Orderline` object has a property of type `int` called '`price`'. What I want to do is, given a customerId, I should get all customer information(Order and Orderline) and  the collection of `Orderline` objects should be ordered by `Orderline's` price property. I've left out all other details for clarity.

Note: In this case the relation between `Customer` and `Order` is `1 to 1`. A customer can have only 1 order, an `Order` may contain many `Orderlines` as you may infer from the collection type.

Many thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from customer in session.Query<Customer>()
            let order = customer.Order
            from orderline in order.Orderlines
            orderby orderlines.price
            select new
            {
                CustomerId = customer.Id,
                CustomerName = customer.Name,
                OrderId = order.Id,
                OrderLineId = orderline.Id,
                Price = orderline.Price,
            };

var results = query.ToLookup(a => a.CustomerId)
    .Select(g => new CustomerDto
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        CustomerName = g.First().CustomerName,
        OrderLines =  g.Select(a => new OrderLineDto(a.OrderLineId, a.Price)).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Voila! Here I got it, we use 'let', thank you very much, this helped me a lot and I'm now more clear with linq